# Remote enum list for value validation - in OpenAPI specification

Tags: swagger, api-design, openapi

I am attempting to define schema in OpenAPI 3.0.2 specification.
I want one of the properties to validate against list of values.

Normally, I get to do this with enum.

```
components:
  schemas:
    catalog:
      title: title here
      description: describing it here
      properties:
        catalogitemid:
          description: catalog identifier
          type: string
          enum: 
            - item1347
            - item9081
            - item5720
        catalogitemname:
          description: catalog item name
          type: string
      required:
        - catalogitemid
        - catalogitemname
      additionalProperties: false
```

But I want this enum list to be a remote YAML/JSON instead.

Reason: This list needs to be updated periodically (2000+ values). And I want to avoid that forces updating this API.

Below $ref approach fails:

```
components:
  schemas:
    catalog:
      title: title here
      description: describing it here
      properties:
        catalogitemid:
          description: catalog identifier
          type: string
          enum:
            $ref: 'https://remote/path/to/catalog/list.yaml#/components/schemas/catalogitemid/enum'
        catalogitemname:
          description: catalog item name
          type: string
      required:
        - catalogitemid
        - catalogitemname
      additionalProperties: false
```

Errors:

Line `catalog` causes

`should have required property '$ref'`

`missingProperty: $ref`

`should match exactly one schema in oneOf`

And line `enum` causes

`should be array`

What would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

#### "Vanilla" OpenAPI

OpenAPI Specification only allows `$ref` in certain contexts, not everywhere. It's not not possible to `$ref` just the `enum` value list, but you can `$ref` the entire property schema:

```yaml
# This won't work
enum:
  $ref: 'https://...'

# This will work
properties:
  catalogitemid:
    $ref: 'https://remote/path/to/enums/catalog-list.yaml'
```

The example above assumes that the `list.yaml` file contains:

```yaml
description: catalog identifier
type: string
enum: 
  - item1347
  - item9081
  - item5720
  ...
```

#### Using Preprocessors

That said, there are tools such as [json-refs](https://github.com/whitlockjc/json-refs) or [openapi-preprocessor](https://github.com/dolmen-go/openapi-preprocessor/) that can resolve JSON References and JSON Pointers in any places of a document. You could use them to pre-process the original spec from your question, which would produce a valid resolved OpenAPI definition that can then be used with OpenAPI-compliant tools.

Comment: This works by pushing the *entire* schema def for `catalogitemid` to remote YAML. Which I need to avoid. Pushing *enum only* to remote seems to be unsupported, though this requirement situation seems pretty valid.

Comment: @C.Derx you could use a preprocessor to resolve $refs in unsupported places. I updated the answer.

Comment: The master API doc will still end up requiring update each time. Thanks for pointing this one out though, I believe I will be able to use it in another context.

Comment: There are no other ways I'm afraid. You can submit an enhancement request in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues.